# AWS architecture help for running database dumps

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mysql, amazon-elb

I have mysql running on one ec2-instance and tableau uses this database. mysqldump runs from production servers every 4 hours during which the system is down for probably 10-15 mins due to the dump. I am planning to have another ec2 instance with mysql running and and elb on top of these two instances so that the system wont be down trough the dump. For this I might have to de-register the instances from elb during the dump and register them back after the dump. Is this the right way to do it in the situations like this?

Comment: Please clarify how the intended connection looks like.

Comment: @mootmoot , I mean I would like to have 2 instances of mysql running on different linux boxes with an ELB on the top and run dumps on the servers at different times. This is what I was thinking. As Mark was mentioning , I am not sure whether this would work or not!!!

Comment: If `mysqldump` is taking your site down, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot .actually, the systems is down when loading it. I would drop the current one and load the dump

Comment: Ohhhhh, I see what you are doing, now.  Why would you not just set one machine as a replication slave of the other, so the data on the read-only machine would essentially always be current?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the idea Michael. How frequent would the replication be..is it continues?  We have a production server from which the data comes to the reporting server..so the prod could be set up as a master and reporting as slave??

Comment: Yes.  It's near real-time.  If your slave is powerful enough to handle the workload, the replication delay can be only a few milliseconds.  It is called "asynchronous" because it's not literally instantaneous, and because the master does not wait for the slave, or need to know whether the slave has caught up or not.  But it's a continuous flow of events from master to slave. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication.html

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks Michael. Will try to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an ELB with MySQL servers. The ELB wouldn't know which server was master and which was slave, so it wouldn't know which to send updates to.

Is there any reason you aren't using Amazon's RDS service for your database servers? It provides automated snapshots that don't cause any down-time. It also makes it easy to create a read-replica against which you could perform mysqldumps without affecting the main server.

Comment: AMAZON RDS costs a little more, and thats the reason we dont want use RDS

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are taking logical backups of your system every 4 hours. Logical backups in most cases should only be used in a worst case scenario. In the event of a restore, logical backups are very slow compared to alternatives, such as snapshots and binary backups.  If snapshoting using Amazon RDS or any of the other multitude of alternatives out there in your environment is not an option, I would look into [Xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/index.html). This is a free stand alone HOT online binary backup tool that can be used with a Vanilla install of MySQL. This should not bring down your production server, assuming you are using InnoDB and not an alternative storage engine such as MyISAM. I personally used it for hot online binary backups and to automate building slaves in my previous work environment.  A binary backups bottleneck is your network speed in terms of the restore process and is exponentially faster than a logical backup.

If setting up another MySQL instance is your only option look into GTID replication and/or Master-Passive HA environment in order to take the mysqldump off of the secondary non-active production server so that your production environment does not go down.

The bottom line is that you should not be taking production down to do a logical backup every 4 hours.  This is def not ideal in any production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Amazon Database Migration Service (https://aws.amazon.com/dms/). It allows you to do zero-downtime database migration or just synchronization.